# Are non-default EventStore projection delimiters valid?

Tags: eventstoredb

A quick question I'm hoping the community can share some experience on:

Is there a a best practice for projection delimiters? In other words, is "-" a *set in stone* best practice (as in a projection name like: $stats-127.0.0.1:2113) or can "_" and other delimiters be safely used (as in something like: $stats_127.0.0.1:2113.). Does anyone have experience using alternative delimiters (positive or negative)...any 'gotchas' I'm not thinking about if we head down the path of alternative delimiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about stats but $by-category projection is editable and although its code is not JavaScript and cannot be edited, you will see the dash there and you can change it. When do save it, the default category projection will use your character as category separator instead of the dash. There's [a thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/event-store/TPNhL2pGjAw/iBFHEkGSWrsJ) in the mailing link about this.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey - good info and thanks for the thread link - I hadn't seen that one yet.